# 'Time step too small' Error when simulating d-flip-flop in LTSpice

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice, simulation

Im just looking to simulate a 3 bit counter in LTSpice and im receiving an error during simulation:

`Analysis: time step too small; time = 1.1e-009, timestep = 1.125e-019: trouble with d-flop instance a3`

so the circuit im simulating looks as so:

[image]

and the clock/simulation parameters can be seen here:

[image]

where the voltage source parameters are as follows:

[image]

could anyone possibly give me some pointers as to why I might be receiving such errors and how it may be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Try getting rid of all the floating inputs in your schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka just tie them to ground?

Comment: Look up what the data sheet tells you about where to connect them.

Comment: @Andyaka Okay, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I would say nearly 9,000 million steps per nanosecond is a bit small.

Comment: @Andyaka There is no need to do that with A-devices: unused inputs are automatically discarded from the simulation (or considered tied to the 8th pin, ground).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a delay for the `dflop`, through the parameter `td`. The reason is that the state at the output and at the input coincide without any delay, and (quote from the manual, `LTspice > Circuit Elements > A. Special Functions`):

> The gates and Schmitt trigger devices supply no timestep information to the simulation engine by default. That is, they don't look when they are about to change state and make sure there's a timestep close to either side of the state change.

Which happens is that if the output changes, it must be because the input has changed state. But if the output and the input are tied directly, and there is no delay between the two states, then the solver sees a simultaneous change at the output and at the input, but that can't be since the output can only change if the input has changed.

The solver then tries to reduce the timestep to detect what happened that made both the input and the output change states seemingly at the same time. And it will continue to reduce the timestep, but because both states are reduced to one, due to the direct connection, no matter how much it reduces it, it can't separate the two states. When the timestep has become too small to reduce, it complains.

The solution is very simple: add `td=1...100n`, `td=10n` is a good enough value. Don't hesitate to add it to the other gates, too. If a delay is present, then the output will change state only after `td` seconds, which means the solver has time to see a change happening at both states, but separately, in a way that makes sense. And, if you think about it, in real life there is always some amount of delay, no change happens instantaneously (thank goodness for causality).

Also, there's no need to set the `trise/tfall` of the source to 1 millionth times smaller than the period; 100...1000 times is enough, unless your requirements are specific (which I doubt).

In addition to `td`, there are also other temporal parameters that can only help in the long run. Two of them, `tau` and `tripdt` are ones that I warmly recommend to anyone.  For this case, `tau=10n tripdt=10n` would help you just fine. What these do is they force the solver to only reduce its timestep if there is a change at the output that happens in less than `tripdt` seconds. `tau` forces a 1st order RC time constant of 10 ns, so for `tripdt` seconds, the engine will slow down, compute the output, then return to a large timestep. This helps preserve sharp edges, but smooth enough to avoid hiccups in the derivative, while also being very fast elsewhere.

Comment: Such an excellent answer.  Only thing I'd like to add is if the user is unfamiliar with adding these A-device instance parameters, then check out the `160.asc` example in `\examples\Educational`.  There are a few AND gates in there with `td` defined.  Right-click on the symbol to see what they did there.  You can add more parameters on the same line by separating them with spaces.

Comment: What an amazing explanation, it all makes sense now. I will look into implementing everything you said. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks from me for the discussion, too!

Comment: @jf192210 If you think this answers your problem, then mark it as solved (the check mark), so that others, in the future, searching for similar problems, will see this question as having an accepted answer. Upvoting is optional and it means that you found the answer useful (it's a way of saying thank you without cluttering the comments' section with "+1" or "thanks").