# 7474 flip-flop- D simulation

Tags: flipflop

I'm trying to use a D flip-flop 7474 for my project.

When I tried to simulate it, this warning appears (see picture.)

My parameters for input clock are:

- OFFTIME = 0.1S
- ONTIME = 0.1S
- DELAY = 0
- STARTVAL = 0
- OPPVAL = 1.

Can someone explain why this warning appears?

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: looks like a simulator bug on RUN, power up... add a tiny cap to D see what happens...

Comment: i tried like you said, but yes it's seems like you said the simulator has a bug because sometimes it work and sometime dosen't .

Comment: Does the cap have any effect on the risetime?  What SIM is it so I know not to recommend it.  I use Falstad's browser sim.

Comment: I use OrCAD Capture for simulation, idk why when i use a large Transient simulation such as 10 s that errors appear again, when i switch to  1 sec it dosen't

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/526021/95619)? At the very least it should solve the problem if a delay is added.

Comment: Transients are usually in nano or microseconds why 10s?  This works far better at any speed but fewer variables. https://tinyurl.com/y4g6be4y  and ideal drivers

Comment: I need to implement the circuit above, I add a photo to my question. The thing is the circuit must provide 2 S/H signals with 30 ms width, and that's why I thought that the 100 ms is the right value for clock signal.